# console emulator. help writing input function

Tags: javascript, html, input, console, emulation

for a project I'm working on, I have a console emulator (as shown below), but I have run into one problem; receiving user input. I need it to create a text box, wait for the user to hit enter, then return the value in the text box, OR if the textbox is empty when enter is pressed, move to the next line with another textbox (same thing until input is received), however, other methods are fine as long as they provide this style of input. the code that does this should be put in the function "input". In the below code, the div 'console' should read:

```
1
23[textbox]
[whatever the user entered]
```

---

if someone could show me a function that performs this, it would be greatly appereciated

---

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<style>
div
{
font-family: Consolas;
color: #ffffff;
background: #000000;
height: 310px;
width: 670px;
overflow-y: scroll;
outline: 100px;
outline-color: #888888;
margin: 0;
}
p
{
margin: 0;
}
#headbar
{
background: #0000ff;
color: orange;
height: 20px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 650px;
}
#redx
{
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
color: black;
background: red;
overflow: auto;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 650px;
margin-top: -20px;
padding: auto;
}
#console
{
font-size: 15;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
br
{
margin: 0;
}
input
{
margin: 0;
}
</style>
<div id="headbar">
<p style ="margin-left: 5">file://C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/User/Desktop/th-df.html</p>
</div>
<div id="redx">
X
</div>
<div id = "console">
<script>
function output(text)
{
document.write(text);
}
function endl()
{
document.write("<br/>");
}
function input()
{
return 0;
}
output("1");
endl();
output("2");
output("3");
var foo = input();   
output(foo);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't really asking for help. I suggest you do more research. Like "Handling user input javascript", "HTML input text", "javascript detecting key events", "javascript get input values", "HTML javascript appending elements" "html javascript changing input values". Don't just output pure text - use HTML elements - use an HTML text input for user input

Comment: `var myUserValue = prompt('Enter your value:');`

Comment: function output(text)
    {
    document.write("<p>" + text + "</p>");
    }
    function endl()
    {
    document.write("<br/>");
    }
    function handleInput()
    {
    var userPut;
    userPut = parseInt(document.getElementById('userInput').value);
    return userPut;
    }
    function input()
    {
    document.write('<form id="userInput"><input type="text" class="textbox"/><input type="submit"/ class="submit" onClick="handleInput"></form>');
    }
    output("1");
    endl();
    output("2");
    output("3");
    input();
    var foo = handleInput();
    output(foo);